# Does numpy.correlate differ from scipy.signal.correlate if both are used on a 1D array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

The documentation of scipy's correlate function claims that it can be used for N-dimensional arrays

> scipy.signal.correlate(in1, in2, mode='full', method='auto')
>
> Cross-correlate two N-dimensional arrays.
> Cross-correlate in1 and in2, with the output size determined by the mode Argument.

While numpy's correlate can only be used for 1-D sequences.

> numpy.correlate(a, v, mode='valid')
>
> Cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences. This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal processing texts:
>
> c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])
>
> with a and v sequences being zero-padded where necessary and conj
> being the conjugate.

So do these functions differ if both are used on two 1-D arrays? If no, what is the usecase for numpy.correlate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the scipy implementation will call the numpy version in some cases, but will also use a faster FFT based implementation when it's likely to be faster.  see [`choose_conv_method`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.choose_conv_method.html) or the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L228) for more details

this "duplication" is so that numpy can provide an optimised base of functions that is often extended by scipy to provide more complete coverage of functionality (which is generally less optimised, but still mostly native code so pretty fast and numerically stable).  other examples of this apparent duplication are the linear algebra functionality (`linalg` packages) and fourier transforms (where numpy provides a few limited functions, and scipy exports most of `fftpack`)

Comment: _"will try and call the numpy version if it can"_ strikes me as rather misleading. IIRC default method is "auto" which will dispatch to fftconvolve if possible and opportune. In particular, the numpy version being more optimized may be correct in the niche case of direct correlation, but often---I would go as far as saying typically---fft based correlation/convolution simply the faster algorithm.

Comment: @PaulPanzer have done some reading and updated my answer, does that make more sense now?

Comment: Well, there is nothing left that would fly in the face of something I really know. Just be sure to clearly mark conjecture as conjecture and only state as fact things you are reasonably sure about.

Comment: @PaulPanzer yup, that's what I try to do. it's the "unknown unknowns" that cause problems!